# How to execute loop until user selects Cancel upon prompt?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, ascii, do-while

I'm writing a program where the user input is broken down into letters and then displayed as ASCII characters.

User may enter an input into the prompt box over and over until he selects `Cancel`, presses the `Enter` key or the `Esc` key.

For example, if you enter 'Hello' followed by 'Bye' when prompted, and the 3rd time you just press the `Enter` key without typing anything, you should see this:

```
Word entered is "Hello"
H = 72
e = 101
l = 108
l = 108
o = 111

Word entered is "Bye"
B = 66
y = 121
e = 101
```

My problem is

1) the "Word entered is..." line does not appear, and

2) the prompt message executes only once regardless of whether user leaves it blank or not.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<script>
    do {
        var word = prompt ("Please enter a word of your choice");
        if (word == null)
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Word entered is " + "\"" + word + "\"";
        else
            break;
    } while (word == null);

    var letter = "<ul>";

    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        letter += word[i] + " = " + word.charCodeAt(i) + "<br>";
    }

    letter += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = letter;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need separate the "words" by " ", and list the letters for each word.

```js
// this function make the variables not glabel.
(function() {
  var words = '';

  while (words === '') {
    // get the input until something not empty or 'Esc'
    words = prompt("Please enter a word of your choice");
  };

  // this function will return the HTML which will list the letters of the word
  var listLetters = function(word) {
    letters = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      letters = letters + word[i] + " = " + word[i].charCodeAt() + "<br>";
    }
    return letters;
  }

  // get target
  var t = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  // empty the target
  t.innerHTML = '';

  // process the inputs
  words.split(' ').forEach(function(word) {
    // print the word
    t.innerHTML += 'Word entered is "' + word + '"<br>';
    // list the letters
    t.innerHTML += listLetters(word) + '<br>';
  });

})();
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if they did not enter a word and then you're displaying the word variable. You only want to display the word that they chose if it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code https://jsfiddle.net/q41gm0j6/

Basically you are missing a return;

```
  (function(){
    do {
     var word = prompt ('Please enter a word of your choice');
       if (word === '' || word === null){
         word = '';
         var t = document.getElementById('myDiv');
         t.innerHTML = 'Word entered is' + word;
         return;
        }
        else break;
    } while (word === null);
      var letter = '<ul>';
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        letter += word[i] + ' = ' + word.charCodeAt(i) + '<br>';
      }
      letter += '</ul>';
      document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML += letter;
   })();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using functions?

Comment: you can remove the (function(){}(); I added, all it does is to make sure the script doesn't run until the html page is loaded. If you place your javascript code somewhere under myDiv, then you don't need that so the code is what you wrote removing the first and last lines

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you wanted initially, there you go https://jsfiddle.net/q41gm0j6/1/ this will do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

Check this plunker code, i have created for you to achieve the desired functionality. Hope this helps you.

the reason of your problem 1 is that you are overwriting the innerHTML of the div that why the "Word entered is..." line does not appear

https://plnkr.co/edit/RN0yNxDAsTSQQeSvGYb9?p=info

```
window.onload = function() {
var word = "";
do {
    word = prompt ("Please enter a word of your choice");

     if(word !== null){

     var span = document.createElement("span");

          span.innerHTML = "Word entered is " + "\"" + word + "\"";

          document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(span);


          var ul = document.createElement("ul");

          var letter = "<ul>";

          for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
              letter += word[i] + " = " + word.charCodeAt(i) + "<br>";
          }

          letter += "</ul>";


          ul.innerHTML = letter;

          document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(ul);
}

} 

while (word !== null);

}
```